# Cordova build | Run failed - compileDebugJavaWithJavac

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I have a problem with building my **Android platform** on **Apache Cordova**.

Version numbers:

- Android @5.0.1 (Samsung galaxy S4)
- Cordova @6.1.1 (updated from 5.1.1 on 07/04/2016)
- Ionic @1.7.14
- Windows @7

I could build my project yesterday, but since today I get errors when trying to build or run my cordova app. I have tried to remove and add my android platform, but that didn't work (it only made thing worse).

---

**Execution failed**

When I run "*Cordova build android*" or "*Cordova run android*" I get the following error:

> Execution failed for task ':CordovaLib:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
>
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

The stacktrace gives the following:

> :CordovaLib:compileDebugJavaWithJavac C:\Users\me\Desktop\myProjects\testProject\platforms\android\CordovaLib\src\org\apache\cordova\CordovaInterfaceImpl.java:222: error: cannot find symbol getActivity().requestPermissions(permissions, requestCode);

I cannot seem to resolve this error. I have a valid java path in my environment variables and I have installed the following **Android SDK build tools**:

- 23.0.3
- 23.0.2
- 23.0.1
- 22.0.1
- 21.1.2
- 20
- 19.1

---

**What I tried**

I tried *cordova platform add android@5.0.1*, but that gives me *unknown platform version*. So I have to set it to version 21 manually in the **Android manifest** and **project.properties**.

Also if I run *cordova platform add android@5.1.1* cordova somehow overrides this and installs the platform for android version 23 (6.0).

I tried downgrading to Cordova version 5.1.1, but that still gave me the same error.

I tried changing the Java path, with no result.

I updated my Android SDK tools and Android SDK platform tools, No difference.

---

**Solution**

It seemed that my npm_cache was corrupt. I had to remove it, so that it was recreated by Cordova. After this I could build and run again. 
*File location:* C:\Users\.cordova\lib 
and then remove the npm_cache folder.

Comment: There might be something wrong with your android platform template. Try deleting "users/user/.cordova/lib/npm_cache" folder. And remove the platform add the platform again and then build again.

Comment: @ElvisXia could you make a answer from that, so that I can accept it? 
It worked. It seems like the cache was corrupted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There might be something wrong with your android platform template. Try deleting "users/user/.cordova/lib/npm_cache" folder,which caches your platform files.

After that, remove the platform of your project and add it again.

Comment: Hello, I can't find the folder .cordova?

Comment: Me too, i can't find the .cordova folder

Comment: I found the folder accidentaly when i ran `npm cache clean whatever` which gives you error telling you where you locate npm error log and the path is similar to which @elvis mentioned