# ionic build android failed - compileDebugJavaWithJavac

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

This is my very first project using ionic 1.7.16. When I run **ionic build android** on my mac, I get the error below.

Tried deleting ~/.cordova/lib/npm_cache, but it didn't help

android platform target is 22

The app was built using the following tutorials, which runs fine when I use ionic serve

- part 1:
  http://www.joshmorony.com/integrating-google-maps-with-an-ionic-application/
- part 2:
  http://www.joshmorony.com/part-1-using-the-http-service-in-ionic-to-dynamically-load-google-map-markers/
- part 3:
  http://www.joshmorony.com/part-3-advanced-google-maps-integration-with-ionic-and-remote-data/

During the app dev, I run the following commands:

```
ionic start ionic-maps blank
ionic setup sass
ionic platform add ios
ionic platform add android
bower install ngCordova
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-geolocation
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-network-information
ionic serve
```

ionic build android errors

```
    MacBook-Pro:ionic-maps XYZ$ ionic build android
Running command: /Users/XYZ/projects/madpaws/ionic/ionic-maps/hooks/after_prepare/010_add_platform_class.js /Users/XYZ/projects/madpaws/ionic/ionic-maps
add to body class: platform-android
ANDROID_HOME=/Users/XYZ/Library/Android/sdk
JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home
:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:checkDebugManifest
:CordovaLib:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileLint
:CordovaLib:copyDebugLint UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:mergeDebugProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:packageDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:checkDebugManifest
:CordovaLib:prepareDebugDependencies
:CordovaLib:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:packageDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileDebugJavaWithJavac/Users/XYZ/projects/madpaws/ionic/ionic-maps/platforms/android/CordovaLib/src/org/apache/cordova/CordovaInterfaceImpl.java:222: error: cannot find symbol
        getActivity().requestPermissions(permissions, requestCode);
                     ^
  symbol:   method requestPermissions(String[],int)
  location: class Activity
/Users/XYZ/projects/madpaws/ionic/ionic-maps/platforms/android/CordovaLib/src/org/apache/cordova/CordovaInterfaceImpl.java:228: error: cannot find symbol
        getActivity().requestPermissions(permissions, requestCode);
                     ^
  symbol:   method requestPermissions(String[],int)
  location: class Activity
/Users/XYZ/projects/madpaws/ionic/ionic-maps/platforms/android/CordovaLib/src/org/apache/cordova/CordovaInterfaceImpl.java:233: error: cannot find symbol
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
                                                       ^
  symbol:   variable M
  location: class VERSION_CODES
/Users/XYZ/projects/madpaws/ionic/ionic-maps/platforms/android/CordovaLib/src/org/apache/cordova/CordovaInterfaceImpl.java:235: error: cannot find symbol
            int result = activity.checkSelfPermission(permission);
                                 ^
  symbol:   method checkSelfPermission(String)
  location: variable activity of type Activity
/Users/XYZ/projects/madpaws/ionic/ionic-maps/platforms/android/CordovaLib/src/org/apache/cordova/CordovaActivity.java:493: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
    @Override
    ^
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
5 errors

 FAILED
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':CordovaLib:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 3.779 secs
Error: Error code 1 for command: /Users/XYZ/projects/madpaws/ionic/ionic-maps/platforms/android/gradlew with args: cdvBuildDebug,-b,/Users/XYZ/projects/madpaws/ionic/ionic-maps/platforms/android/build.gradle,-Dorg.gradle.daemon=true,-Pandroid.useDeprecatedNdk=true
```

Comment: Have you tried this?? http://stackoverflow.com/a/36571805/5119391

Comment: yes, I have. I've stated this in the description above "Tried deleting ~/.cordova/lib/npm_cache, but it didn't help"

Comment: Sorry, can you solved that problem??